# How to send multiple messages using one socket in android(java,kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make an app that sends a message to my server and receives the response and updates my app every second  . The problem is each time I have to make a new socket and send the message and then close the socket which is slow . I'm wondering if there's a way that I can make one socket and send my messages and when I'm done close the socket. This is how my function works.

```
public suspend fun dataexchange1(address: String, port: Int, message: String): String? {

    val socket = Socket(address, port)

    val Input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket!!.getInputStream()))
    val output = DataOutputStream(socktst!!.getOutputStream())
  

    output!!.write(message.toByteArray())

    var response= Input.readLine()
 
    Input.close()
    socket!!.close()
    return response.toString()
}
```

Comment: Don't close the streams - no idea how you have set it up, but usually you'd have 2 threads one for out and one for in. Closing either stream closes the socket ..?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to create a loop where you empty the buffer each time a message is sent, and resending the new message.